# What is the new SSRS 2012 Web Service End Point (SharePoint 2013 Integrated)

Tags: reporting-services, sharepoint-2013

I have deployed the SharePoint Service Application of Reporting Services 2012 on SharePoint 2013 in SharePoint integrated mode.

My SSRS Service Application runs on a dedicated box. (WFE and SSRS are not co-located)

When I read this documentation from Microsoft

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155398.aspx

none of the URLs work.

Does anyone know the right URL when using SSRS 2012 with SharePoint 2013, Integrated Mode, on distributed nodes, where is the SSRS Web Service?